# Why does the Java ArrayList class return a boolean for add?

Tags: java, arraylist

My teacher gave me this analogy for a method I am writing.  I still don't get why the add method returns a boolean?

Wouldn't it make more sense for it to return nothing?

Comment: Because of the `List` interface.

Comment: @EJP not really. It's because of the `Collection` interface, which `List` extends. A list's add method always returns `true`.

Comment: I would think it would make more sense to return the updated version of the list- this would have come in handy for me several times

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This comes from [`Collection<E>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#add-E-) interface, since the interface is used as an ancestor class for all kinds of collections, it makes sense to return a `boolean` to inform if `add` effectively changed the collection.

This is useful for collections like [`Set<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#add(E)) which doesn't change if the element added was already present inside the collection. In case of a `List<T>` Java enforces by design to return `true`, so if you want to notify the caller that the operation didn't succeed you must find another way (eg. throw an exception).

This is clearly stated in `Collection<E>.add` documentation:

> If a collection refuses to add a particular element for any reason other than that it already contains the element, it must throw an exception (rather than returning false). This preserves the invariant that a collection always contains the specified element after this call returns.

Basically the value returned doesn't indicate failure but if a successful add operation changed the collection. Any failure must be notified by throwing an exception.

Comment: @StephenC: that is true in general but it's not true for Java `List<T>`, you are enforced to return `true` if inheriting from `List<T>` as specified in its `add` contract.

Comment: @StephenC other `Collection<T>` may return false, but the `List` interface does in fact state `add` must return true. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add(E)

Comment: @Jack `Arrays.asList(1)` try to add something to that `List` **or** [`Collections.singletonList(T)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#singletonList-T-).

Comment: @ElliotFrisch it throws an `UnsupportedOperationException`

Comment: @ElliottFrisch: your comment is irrelevant, regardless of your ability to `add` elements to a `List<T>`, `add` method must return `true` by design. Indeed `Collections.unmodifiableList` doesn't return `false` to `add` but throws an `UnsupportedOperationException`. That's not a good design imho but it's the one chosen by SDK designers.

Comment: @StephenC: I rewrote that part of the answer to be clearer.

Answer (score 4):

The Javadoc for [`ArrayList.add(E)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add-E-) explains that it

> Returns:
>   true (as specified by [Collection.add(E)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#add-E-))

Which says

> Returns:
>   true if this collection changed as a result of the call

If it didn't return a `boolean`, then a caller would have to test the `List` or check an `Exception` or there would be no way to tell if the call succeeded. I think it was easier (and faster) to return a `boolean`.

Comment: Hmmm. Adding to the list will always succeed (other than ridiculous edge cases such as adding more than `Integer.MAX_VALUE` elements), so the caller isn't going to learn anything. It's a perfunctory `return true` for a list, only returning boolean because it's a `Collection`.

Answer (score 2):

Simply put (and this is what helped me understand it). the boolean you're returning indicates that your `add()` **was successful**.

Consider this, if you didn't return a boolean, how would you know that you successfully added something? You'd have to manually check to see that you indeed added something. It's "unnecessary", but it's clever.